# When do we use "itself"?

Tags: reflexive-pronouns

Please explain the difference between these sentences.

> 1. The door is quite heavy.
> 2. The door **itself** is quite heavy.

When do we use *itself*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Itself** is used to single out *the door* from amongst other factors.

For example, if you lived in a trailer and needed to transport it to another city, you would enlist the help of a special moving company to move it. However the price of moving it is based on its weight. When they weigh it, they give you a ridiculous quote for moving it. You can't believe how expensive it is and you question the overall weight of your trailer.

> YOU: "There's no way my trailer weighs two tons!"
>
> MAN: "The door itself weights 200 pounds!"

Here you could also use **the door alone** or **just the door**

In another scenario, you want to get a price quote for painting your trailer. The painter comes out and gives you a ridiculous quote. When you ask why it's so high, he points to the door:

> MAN: That door is going to be $100 extra.
>
> YOU: It's just a door!
>
> MAN: The door itself is no problem, it's that fancy woodwork around it
>   - it'll have to be hand-painted.

Here you could also use "the door in and of itself" or "the door per se"